# Using a Magic Item as an Edge Pre-requisite

Tags: savage-worlds

Can a character take an Edge with an Advance that uses an Edge they got from a Magic Item as a pre requisite. For Example say I had  a "Gum  Shield of Frenzy" could I get Improved Frenzy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few options here. I'm a generous and fun-loving GM so I've sorted them in my preference.

**Yes, but only when using the item.**
Let the character take *Improved Frenzy*, but they must maintain the prerequisites to use *Improved Frenzy*. If they stop using the shield, they lose all benefits of *Improved Frenzy* until they regain *Frenzy* (by any means.)

**No, but make the edges cumulative.**
Let the character learn the *Frenzy* edge. The shield provides the benefit of *Frenzy* or *Improved Frenzy* depending on who wields it.

**No, suck it up.**
It's a tough world. Just because you have a crutch that lets you walk doesn't mean you can use it to run.

Comment: Of the options above, I would probably go for 2, Make the edges cumulative.

Comment: I like 1 & 3. I think it probably depends on the background feel of the Campaign.

Comment: I think 2 is the simplest option besides "suck it up".  I would personally roll with that.